# How can I tell if I have Samsung or Google calendar app installed?

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-note-3, google-calendar

I have a calendar app installed (rooted Samsung Galaxy Note 3, Android 4.3)

App Info shows version "4.3-N900VVRUBMJ7", which matches Samsung's instaled Android version.

How can I tell if it's a standard Google Calendar app, or Samsung's version of it or Samsung's proprietary app?

(the main reason is that I need to ask questions about it here, and I need to specify which calendar app I'm using :)

Comment: In most cases the logo can tell. Search for the Google Calendar logo on google images and match it with the one installed in your device.

Comment: @TanmayVij - by logo, do you mean the icon? Thanks

Comment: Isn't there an "About"  in the app? What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out an answer.

Went to Google Play and opened Google Calendar. It had "Install" button, meaning it wasn't already installed.

Coupled with the Calendar app's ID matching Samsung firmware #, it means the app I have is Samsung's calendar, not Google.